# Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 ?refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I cannot connect postgresql to docker in spring boot

```
[![it is giving following error Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08001
Error Code : 0
Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.][1]][1]
```

below my application.yml file

```
app:
  datasource:
    main:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/amigoscode
      username: amigoscode
      password: 'password'
      pool-size: 30

server:
  error:
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-message: always
```

below my docker-compose.yaml file

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

I am getting error image below
[image]

I have tried all stackoverflow error and other suggestions it did not help even I have tried this one as well I want to know where exactly I am making mistake

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  I saw a very similar question raised recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you database is running in a different container than your app is running, you have to use the container name in the jdbc-url not `localhost`:  `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/amigoscode`

```
app:
  datasource:
    main:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://postgre:5432/amigoscode
      username: amigoscode
      password: 'password'
      pool-size: 30

server:
  error:
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-message: always
```